# How to tell the keyboard layout from the box?

Tags: keyboard, usb

I have a brand new Apple wired keyboard (someone gave it to me for free). I want to sell it on eBay. How can I tell the layout just by looking at the box?

[image: keyboard barcode sticker]

I tried to Google every number on the picture, without definitive results. The model numbers A1243 and MB110B/A can belong any layout. This is true for the barcode as well. The number starting with 4R produces no results.

Edit: two more pictures
[image: another sticker]

[[image: front picture[3]]

Comment: A picture of the actual keyboard would be really useful; the picture on the front of the box...

Comment: I have added two more pictures, not sure how that will help though.

Comment: argh... they used to picture the keyboard from the front. All you can tell from that is "it's not American"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a British layout. I found this out by googling 'MB110' while restricting the results to different countries and looking for model numbers that pop up.

Examples:

MB110B/A and MB110B/B are British layouts

MB110D/B is German

MB110RS/B is Russian

etc.